# Integrating Hark with ROS-matlab

Tags: ros, localization, matlab, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!
I am trying to localize a sound source and use that information in matlab. I have integrated ROS with matlab (R2012b) and ROS with Hark. I am also able to visualize the localisation information in HARK. But I need the localisation data in Matlab (to control a robot in Gazebo). The problem I am facing is that the source localization data in hark is outputted as a data type ObjectRef. Can anyone help me how to convert this data structure to simple data types like vector, Int or float that can be published as std_msgs or any other technique by which I can subscribe localization data in Matlab. Information about the data type of source can be found at pg. no. 32 of hark-documentation (version2) . Any solution is welcome by which I can get the localization information in Matlab.

System Specs:
Ros Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, Matlab R2012b, Hark version 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173775/integrating-hark-with-ros-matlab/) by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way around but it is not an elegant solution.
1> Create a rosbuild package (at this time hark_mgs do not support catkin package) that would subscribe to hark_msgs and publish any other standard message.
2> Subscribe the newly created topic consisting of std_msgs.

---

Originally posted by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) with karma: 66 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0